# How to change the property signUpUrl in ProviderSignInController in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-social

**In short**

I need to change the property value of a bean defined in the auto configuration of the spring boot, which is not available to configure from `application.properties`

**Descriptive**

I want to change the `signUpUrl` of the bean `ProviderSignInController`. This is not available to change in the properties file according to the documentation.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

So I did somthing like this.

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {

    @Autowired
    public void configureProviderSignInController(ProviderSignInController signInController){
        signInController.setSignUpUrl("/register");
    }
```

and ended up with the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
```

But according to the autoconfiguration this bean should be available

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/social/SocialWebAutoConfiguration.java

Please help and guild me if I'm doing this incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

The error describes that the problem is that you have not instantiated a bean with the type of `ProviderSignInController` in your method signature for `configureProviderSignInController`. Instead, you need to instantiate and configure the controller in one of your configurations with the proper constructor signatures required by the controller:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

    ...

    @Bean
    public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController(
                ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
                UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository) {
        ProviderSignInController controller = new ProviderSignInController(
            connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository,
            new SimpleSignInAdapter());
        controller.setSignUpUrl("/register");
        return controller;
    }

}
```

Alternatively, if you are using XML configurations:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.signin.web.ProviderSignInController">
    <!-- relies on by-type autowiring for the constructor-args -->
    <property name="signUpUrl" value="/register" />
</bean>
```

For more information, consult the [Spring Social docs on enabling provider sign in](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#enabling-provider-sign-in-with-code-providersignincontroller-code).

Comment: Thank you i will check this and get back :)